# Change sql query to LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, sql-to-linq-conversion

How I convert this sql query :

```
Select ID, first_name, last_name, phone_number, room_type, room_floor, room_number, break_fast, lunch, dinner, cleaning, towel, s_surprise, supply_status, food_bill
from reservation
where check_in = '" + "True" + "' AND supply_status= '" + "False" + "'"
```

into LINQ

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something similar to this:

```
var rows = from r in reservation
           where r.check_in == "True" && r.supply_status == "False"
           select r;
```

Comment: need more info to know what you have. my answer is pure theoretic. if you want something correct please give more details: your context your class names etc...

Comment: Thank you very much,it solved when I change it into : r.check_in==true